# “Form submission canceled because the form is not connected” error in new chrome version with ExtJS 6 & Sencha Architect 4

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, filefield

When I submit my form, I get the error “Form submission canceled because the form is not connected” in new Chrome Version. Note that I use a `file field` inside the form panel.

The form was developed using ExtJS 6 Modern Toolkit.

The code for my form:

```js
xtype: 'formpanel',
margin: '20 30',
items: [{
      xtype: 'container',
      id: 'box-img',
      padding: '0 0 30 0',
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
      },
      items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        width: 300,
        layout: {
          type: 'vbox',
          align: 'center',
          pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'image',
            height: 300,
            width: 300
          },
          {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            id: 'foto_',
            itemId: 'foto_',
            bodyAlign: 'center',
            label: 'File Gambar',
            name: 'foto_',
            required: true
          }
        ]
      }]
    },
```

Thanks ,

Comment: what are you really trying to do with these to many containers in you form

Comment: And post your controller code as well thats does not seems your layout or padding problem

Comment: i have been update this form with only one container, but this problem not solved. In my controller i'm only use the form submit function. i hope you can help me